# Period list for grouped datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am very new to pandas and i want to do the following, but getting some troubles with groupby. Please help.

I have a dataframe with many columns one of which is date.
I need a list of distinct month year from it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['02 Jan 2018', '02 Feb 2018', '02 Feb 2018', '02 Mar 2018'], columns=['date'])
datelist = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
datelist = datelist.groupby([datelist.dt.month, datelist.dt.year])
```

when i do `datelist.all()` i get the following,

```
date  date
1     2018         True
2     2018         True
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

I need something like `['Jan 2018', 'Feb 2018']`

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then convert to custom strings with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), get [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values and last convert to `string`s:

```
datelist = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%b %Y').unique().tolist()
print (datelist)
['Jan 2018', 'Feb 2018', 'Mar 2018']
```

Another solution if input format of datetimes is `02 Jan 2018` is split by first whitespace [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), select second value and get `unique` values:

```
datelist = df['date'].str.split(n=1).str[1].unique().tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) (for a Series this would be [`dt.to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)):

```
In [11]: datelist.to_period("M")
Out[11]:
PeriodIndex(['2019-01', '2019-01', '2019-01', '2019-01', '2019-01', '2019-01',
             ...
             '2019-02', '2019-02', '2019-02', '2019-02', '2019-02'],
            dtype='period[M]', freq='M')

In [12]: datelist.to_period("M").unique()
Out[12]: PeriodIndex(['2019-01', '2019-02'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')

In [13]: [str(m) for m in datelist.to_period("M").unique()]
Out[13]: ['2019-01', '2019-02']
```